# How can I check current water levels in Lake George, NSW, Australia?

Tags: australia, sightseeing, weather-and-climate, new-south-wales, canberra

[Lake George](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lake_George_(New_South_Wales)) in New South Wales, Australia, not too far from capital Canberra, is an endorheic (no rivers flowing out) lake famous for regularly "disappearing": it can be dry for years and then fill up again at short notice if the weather conditions are right.

In 2021, after a long dry stretch, [Lake George filled up again](https://www.canberratimes.com.au/story/7603041/lake-george-is-looking-pretty-full-but-just-how-full-is-it-actually/).  But is there **any way to check in real time (or close to it) if there's any water right now?** Open to web cams, weather data, recent satellite imagery, anything.

Comment: Tongue in cheek answer: for $175 you can purchase a [custom satellite photo](https://www.skyfi.com/pricing) of any location on the planet. But I assume there's cheaper solutions :-)

Comment: @JonathanReez Unfortunately the images on Google Maps aren't exactly realtime, they're still showing the lake as dry: https://maps.app.goo.gl/R4HNJqY6ko7vijzz7

Comment: I wonder if this gold could be extracted from https://realtimedata.waternsw.com.au/ or http://www.bom.gov.au/water/7daystreamflow/#id=2122725

Comment: Could the [water storage level of nearby Canberra](http://www.bom.gov.au/water/dashboards/#/water-storages/summary/urban?location=Canberra) be a good proxy for the water level in Lake George?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

I was unable to find any online source tracking water levels in Lake George, but I can now provide photographic evidence that the water level today, 7 April 2023, is **considerable**.